# How to upload a file to S3 using SSIS?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3, ssis

This was my question a few hours ago and just trying to save someone all the effort i had to go through to figure this out.

Basic code on how to upload file to S3 using script task in SSIS. Be sure to add `Amazon.S3.dll` and `Amazon.Core.dll` to your references.

```
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using System.IO;

namespace tests
{
    class Program
    {
        static ScriptMain()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        }

        static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            string path = @"Path to DLLs";
            if (args.Name.Contains("AWSSDK.Core"))
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "AWSSDK.Core.dll"));
            }
            if (args.Name.Contains("AWSSDK.S3"))
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "AWSSDK.S3.dll"));
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void Main()
        {
            string filePath = @"Path to file to be uploaded";
            string bucket = "bllcrdtanalytics/Optimization/test"; //bucket name example
            IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest2);

            PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
            putRequest.FilePath = filePath;
            putRequest.Key = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
            putRequest.BucketName = bucket;
            PutObjectResponse response = s3Client.PutObject(putRequest);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question, but rather than an answer. It's fine to answer your own question, in order to share knowledge with the community, but you should still follow the distinct question and answer format.