# Upload file to S3 Bucket in SSIS project

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ssis, nuget

I'm trying to upload a file to a S3  bucket from a SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) Script Task. I was trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083147/how-to-upload-a-file-to-s3-using-ssis) question, but whenever I click `Ok` to close the Script Task, it says `Scripts contained in the package have compliation errors`.

I have narrowed the error to whenever I add the `AWSSDK.Core.dll` and `AWSSDK.S3.dll` libraries either manually, browsing my files, or via the `AWSSDK.S3` NuGet package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.